# PWM average voltage smoothing

Tags: pwm, buck, motor-controller, smoothing-capacitor

I built an ESC circuit. First, I tested it with a drive frequency of 350 Hz; the speed was at about 20 RPS at a 70% duty cycle.

But when I changed the drive frequency to 20 kHz, I noticed that the speed became less with the same duty cycle. I used a 100 μF electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the motor terminals to solve the problem.

Is what I did alright? And if it is, what is the exact value the capacitor should be?

This is the electronic schematic:

[image]

Comment: How much is the VCC supply for the opto? How much is the load current for FET drain?

Comment: Inductance will increase the motor's impedance at high frequencies. A large C will store energy in HF pulses as DC.

Comment: @Justme it is TLP250 (Gate driver) , 3.3 V .... under 6 A (it is MOSFET)

Comment: @user_1818839 , did i do the right thing by using 100 uF or not ?

Comment: The capacitor across the motor is definitely NOT the correct solution. That will prevent any PWM functionality.

Comment: Maybe the speed went down because you are now switching too fast. Maybe you should increase the PWM frequency a bit more gradually and see if there is a point where you notice the speed going down. Definitely get rid of the 100 uF cap. I am surprised you have not destroyed your MOSFET yet, forcing it to dump current into a 100 uF load.

Comment: All I  need is to smooth PWM voltage that drive motor .. any one know the solution I will be grateful if he tell me .

Comment: No. You do not want to smooth the voltage. It is normal to have "square wave" voltage when using PWM control.

Comment: If you have an oscilloscope, please post a picture of the gate voltage and also of the motor voltage operating at 20 kHz with no capacitor.

Comment: I will try that , but the problem starts at high frequency (20KHz) with lower frequency like 350 Hz i don't have this problem  .. i said that i need solution to smooth PWM signal with efficient way because adding 100 uF solve the problem .... Note : this problem happen only with low duty cycle like 40 % , while with 90 % or 100 % the motor spins at the same speed of 350 Hz PWM

Comment: There is a lot of room between 350 Hz and 20 kHz. You think you need to smooth the PWM signal but you are wrong. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

Motors and capacitors do not go together very well. For the motor it is important the current ripple, not the voltage. The capacitor will make the output voltage smoother, but it brings also high inrush current. The motors do need inductors - it's the analogy of the circuits which need low voltage ripple.

Now the TLP250 and many other gate drivers have a nominal working voltage of 15V. So any voltage below 12V is not suitable for driving a MOSFET.

> I used a 100 μF electrolytic capacitor

So polarized one. Look at you schematics, you have a freewheeling diode D1 that does conduct in the opposite direction, it means the output voltage is not unipolar. Placing a electrolytic cap is a no. go.

Comment: So what is the solution to smooth PWM signal without problem ?